# The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version with local_infile ON

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I know, there are a couple of questions out there, that are focusing on the same Issue, but all suggested fixes are not working for me.

I am running a PHP script in which I a trying to insert a CSV file into my DB using `LOAD DATA INFILE` like this

```
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($db, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($db, $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $database);

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $tpl_vars['filename'] . "' " .
       "INTO TABLE " . $table_name . " " .
       "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '" . $tpl_vars['delimiter'] . "' " .
       "ENCLOSED BY '\"" . $tpl_vars['encapsulation'] . "' " .
       "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' " .
       ($tpl_vars['contains_header'] == 1 ? "IGNORE 1 ROWS" : "") . " " .
       "(" . $columns . ") " .
       $set;

$db->query($sql);
```

The resulting statement looks like thish and is syntactically right. All columns to exist in the table.

```
LOAD data local INFILE '/path/to/file/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 rows (@category, @title, @price, @description) 
SET category = @category, title = @title, price = @price, description = @description;
```

The result I get is

> The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version.

Even if I run the statement in phpMyAdmin it results in

> 2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Because I do not have complete root access to my server I checked my php.ini using `ini_get_all()` and it returned

> mysqli.allow_local_infile: {global_value: "1", local_value: "1", access: 4}

To check the my.cnf I ran `SHOW VARIABLES` on my DB. It returned

> local_infile ON

As far as I can see, everything is configured totally fine to run `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Am I missing something?

My user does have the following GRANTS

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'asdf'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db`.* TO 'user'@'localhost'
```

I am on MariaDB 10.1.44 and PHP 5.5.38.

Comment: are you sure the sql syntax is correct?

Comment: I edited my question above to show how my statement is built. It is syntactically correct. @Dharman, I know. The project I am working for is going to update asap, but at the moment I have to deal with PHP 5. :(

Comment: Shouldn't `\n` be `\\n`?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Nonetheless it does not work. I added more information above. Maybe that helps finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was, that my user did not have File grants.

`GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'asdf'`

did the trick.