# PHP MySQLi can't load data local

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I try to do this code:

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($conn,'{HOST}','{USERNAME}','{PASSWD}','{DBNAME}');
$x = mysqli_query($conn, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/sample.txt' INTO TABLE temp");
if($x){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

and i have this error:

```
The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version
```

On server MariaDB, but it's not mean - just public fork of MySQL.
So, i have in **php.ini** on client:

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = 1
mysql.allow_local_infile = 1
```

I have on server:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.023 sec)
```

**What's wrong and how to resolve it ?**

Comment: Does your user have the necessary permissions? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532908/the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mariadb-version-with-local-infile-on

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819098/error-1148-mysql-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version

Comment: i repeat it from cli version - all ok. what's wrong with php ?

Comment: what mariadb version is it ?